# Odoo - multiple many2one fields that point to the same model

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

Odoo - multiple Many2one fields that point to the same model

1.I would like to know how I can do to obtain two Many2one fields from the same
class, Actually I've only been able to get a many2one field.

**In model A I have two fields**

```
cod_modA = fields.Char()
descr_modA = fields.Char()
```

**I want that from the model B I can obtain two Many2one fields:**

```
rel_cod_modB = fields.Many2one ('cod_modA')   
rel_descr_modB = fields.Many2one ('descr_modA')
```

The purpose of this is to be able to select the register according to cod_modA or according to descr_modA

**currently this is:**

```
rel_cod_modB = fields.Many2one('cod_modA')
rel_descr_modB = fields.Text(related='rel_cod_modB.descrmodA ')
```

2.If I select the field Many2one rel_cod_modB, the field rel_desr_modB is autocomplete.

and if I select the field Many2one rel_descr_modB, the field rel_cod_modB will autoplete

Similar to what happens with related.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code :

**Model A:**

```
model_A1 = fields.Char()
model_desc = fields.Char()
```

**Model B:**

```
model_A1_child = fields.Many2one('modelA')
model_A1_desc = fields.Char(related='model_A1_child.model_desc')
```